# How to bind a Command to a MenuItem in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been reading posts for most of the day and can't find this or figure it out. Pretty much all the questions and answers build the menu in XAML but I'm trying do this in code.

The menu builds fine (there's more to it, just abbreviated here) and enables or disables properly but I can't get the command to execute. There is a button on the menu ribbon that resubmits fine so I know the code on the back end works I just can't seem to figure out how to invoke it from the menu. Any ideas would be nice.

Mouse event to build and display menu from MainView.xaml.cs. There are **'s on the line that needs fixed.

```
private void MainDataGrid_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();

    m.Items.Add(new MenuItem());
    mi = (MenuItem)m.Items[0];
    mi.Header = "Resubmit";
    **mi.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, ResubmitCommand));**
    mi.IsEnabled = MainViewModel.CurrentSelectedItems.Count > 0;
    .
    .
    .
    m.IsOpen = true;
}
```

The ResubmitCommand from my MainViewModel.cs:

```
public ICommand ResubmitCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _resubmitCommand ??
        (_resubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(
        o => Resubmit(),
        o => CanResubmit));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's really aggravating to have someone vote something down when they are too chicken to post a comment explaining why. If you can't think of a reason leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the menu item's `Command` property:

```
mi.Command = ResubmitCommand;
```

By default, `ApplicationCommands.New` only supports the `Ctrl+N` input gesture and is usually bound to the main window. You can bind it to a left-click on the menu item:

```
mi.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New,Resubmit));

var leftClickGesture= new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick);
mi.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, leftClickGesture));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I tried that. I get "The 'ResubmitCommand' does not exist in the current context." It's actually in a different class and executed as a RelayCommand. It's set up like that for the ribbon button but I'm trying to call it from a ContextMenu.

Comment: Awesome, that just about did it. I had to remove the line: mi.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New,Resubmit)); and modify a couple things elsewhere in the code and that did it.

Answer (score 0):

The lines:

```
m.Items.Add(new MenuItem());
mi = (MenuItem)m.Items[0];
```

should be changed to just:

```
m.Items.Add(mi);
```

Comment: That doesn't address the question.